# Render HTML from a string that is stored in a React database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently developing a page in React, and I'm trying to pull HTML content in from a RTDB that has been formatted using use styles

Example of the styling

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
        topcontent:{
          fontSize:10,
        },
        blackBox:{

            paddingBottom:20,

        }
    ...
```

Example of the data in the database.

```
<p className={classes.topcontent}> Content Here <p>
<img src='/img/image.png' width='50%' />
```

...

the object that is rendered

```
return (
<Grid sm={9} xs={12}>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:article.content}} />
</Grid>
);
```

The string stored in the database looks like this, and is passed to ***article.content***

```
<p className={classes.topcontent}>intro copy </p>
<img src='/article/img.png' width='95%' />
<Typography variant='h2' className={classes.titleTwo}>Title Here</Typography>             
<p>Content Here</p>
```

The issue I'm having is that when it renders the makeStyles are not being rendered. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

It works if I hard code the HTML, but when it pulls from the database, it's like the content loads after the page rendered and all the "makeStyles" are missing. I could just use a style sheet and it would work but is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Can we see the code for the makeStyles function? Does it return a promise?

Comment: I'm just using import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'; it works if I hard code the HTML, but when it pulls from the database, it's like the content loads after the page rendered and all the "makeStyles" are missing. I could just use a style sheet and it would work but is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, the content was rending after the page loaded, so I needed to change the content to HTML and, not material UI markup Example:

The content was like this

```
<p className={classes.topcontent}>intro copy </p>
<img src='/article/img.png' width='95%' />
<Typography variant='h2' className={classes.titleTwo}>Title Here</Typography>             
<p>Content Here</p>
```

changes to this,

```
<p class='topcontent'>intro copy  </p>              
<img src='/article/img.png' width='95%' />          
<h2 class='titleTwo'>Title Here</h2>
<p>Content Here</p>
```

and created a style sheet

```
.topcontent{
    font-size: 20px;

}

.titleTwo{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    font-weight: 400;

  }
```

I have to move some of the stylings from https://materializecss.com/ into the css sheet.

I feel there must be a better way to do this, but this will work for now. If you know a better way let me know.